# How to put wildcard entry into /etc/hosts?

Tags: subdomain, wildcard, hosts

I recently wanted to point all subdomains for a test domain, let's say example.com to the localhost. Is there a way to point all requests on *.example.com to resolve to 127.0.0.1

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/118378/in-my-etc-hosts-file-on-linux-osx-how-do-i-do-a-wildcard-subdomain

Answer (score 131, accepted):

It happens that `/etc/hosts` file doesn't support wild card entries.

You'll have to use other services like dnsmasq. To enable it in dnsmasq, just edit `dnsmasq.conf` and add the following line:

```
address=/example.com/127.0.0.1
```

Comment: for wildcard entry - address=/.example.com/127.0.0.1

Comment: @Vivek Its not required

Comment: For ubuntu `dnsmasq` setup see [this one](http://askubuntu.com/questions/150135/how-to-block-specific-domains-in-hosts-file/150180#150180).

Comment: For macosx setup http://passingcuriosity.com/2013/dnsmasq-dev-osx/ is pretty helpful.

Comment: rahilwazir, actually, it is if you dont want all subdomains. # also works as a wild card. I'm personally using `address=/dev#.example.com/127.0.0.1 to make dev123.example.com etc work.

Comment: `dnsmasq` is not able to do this.

Comment: For some reason dnsmasq does not work at all. Is there a way to make sure I configure anything correct?

Comment: I don't know this tool and it does many things other than just hosts file replacement, can you please expand your answer saying how to enable dnsmasq or how to make changes take effect? I did just what you mentioned and got nothing, thank you.

Comment: This works just fine with dnsmasq. Just remember, you have to restart it after changing the config. E.g. `sudo systemctl restart dnsmasq`.

Comment: Is there a way to do this _without_ having to create the same file with different names each time?

Answer (score 11):

**use dnsmasq**

Assuming that you're using a Debian-based dist(ubuntu, mint..), check if it's installed with

```
(sudo) systemctl status dnsmasq
```

**If** it is just disabled, start it with

```
(sudo) systemctl start dnsmasq
```

**If** you have to install it, write

```
(sudo) apt-get install dnsmasq
```

To define domains to resolve edit `/etc/dnsmasq.conf` like this.

```
address=/example.com/127.0.0.1
```

to resolve *.example.com

**! You must reload dnsmasq to take effect for the changes !**

```
systemctl reload dnsmasq
```

Answer (score 10):

Here is the configuration for those trying to accomplish the original goal (wildcards all pointing to same codebase -- install nothing, dev environment ie, XAMPP)

## hosts file (add an entry)

file: /etc/hosts (non-windows)

```
127.0.0.1   example.local
```

## httpd.conf configuration (enable vhosts)

file: /XAMPP/etc/httpd.conf

```
# Virtual hosts
Include etc/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
```

## httpd-vhosts.conf configuration

file: XAMPP/etc/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin admin@example.local
    DocumentRoot "/path_to_XAMPP/htdocs"
    ServerName example.local
    ServerAlias *.example.local
#    SetEnv APP_ENVIRONMENT development
#    ErrorLog "logs/example.local-error_log"
#    CustomLog "logs/example.local-access_log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

restart apache

## create pac file:

save as whatever.pac wherever you want to and then load the file in the browser's network>proxy>auto_configuration settings (reload if you alter this)

```
function FindProxyForURL(url, host) {
  if (shExpMatch(host, "*example.local")) {
    return "PROXY example.local";
  }
  return "DIRECT";
}
```

Comment: Does not works for hosts file on Windows. It will only accept www.example.com

Comment: this does work on windows using the pac file in firefox. I have tested this on multiple windows machines. the hosts file only requires the one entry, the pac file handles the subdomains.

Comment: The original question as I understand it is not about apache at all but on the networking level so I think your response misses the point :/

Comment: for using the pac file in  internet explore see:https://campus.barracuda.com/product/websecurityservice/article/WSS/ConfigProxyWithPACFile/

Comment: Please note that when using a pac file to proxy requests to a host (e.g. localhost), a web server like Apache would use the full URL (including protocol and hostname) in REQUEST_URI variable instead of only the path component.

Comment: Although quite ingenious it does not work for websockets.

Comment: Port is missing. I would provide :80 to be sure. Or else, don't know, maybe browser would pick 3128

Answer (score 2):

It was a simple question, guys. The answer seems to be "no."

The reason I'm looking for information about this topic is that Google just added lots of new top level domains that seem to be designed for abuse, like .zip and .mov.  They only went live five days ago and malicious actors have already set up pages using those domains to steal credentials, install malware, and worse.  Leaving aside questions about Google's motivation, it would be very helpful to have a fast and simple way, that doesn't involve either going to some dubious web page to install someone's shiny new security app, which we rilly rilly swear doesn't have any hidden spy features, or spending a decade learning regex fu, to blacklist everything on all of them.  For that matter, .biz has existed for twenty-two years and I have yet to see the first legitimate thing that uses it. I'd also like to bitbucket all traffic in either direction for .ads, .adult, .ru, .cn, .kr, .xyz, .za, and .zn. Anything and everything, for that matter, that doesn't use one of the original seven .tlds:

.com
.edu
.gov
.int
.mil
.net
.org

has been 100% sketchy AF since day one and it would be ideal for me, in my own personal use case, on my own computers, to point all of it to 0.0.0.0.

Comment: Hi and welcome here. You are right, spoofing is Evil, but I dont know any way to avoid it. Each time a nTLD appears :(

Answer (score 0):

Using wildcard for host file is not possible or require complex method.

Go here to get ip address you wanna block
https://dnsdumpster.com/

enter domain: example.com then roll down. Click on download xlsx of host. All ip of domain and subdomain is listed here.

Copy ip address from excel column to a txt file name ip_address.txt

First, you need enable firewall:

```
sudo ufw enable
```

Second, using this command:

```
while read -r ip_address; do sudo ufw deny out to $ip_address; done < ip_address.txt}
```

Note that you need use "out to" to block outbound connect from your pc to ip. If you use use "from" it only block inbound connect from ip to your pc and user still can get access to ip.

Third, test if ufw work by using:

```
sudo ufw status numbered
```

When you want remove a rule:

```
sudo ufw delete <rule-number>
```

Comment: The question says nothing about *blocking* anything.

Comment: point all requests on *.example.com to resolve to 127.0.0.1 = blocking all subdomain  of example.com !!!

Comment: The question doesn’t mention blocking, that’s your inference. Consider a site like tumblr.com. Each user gets their own subdomain (example.tumblr.com). When doing development work to test that feature, you’d need to resolve *.example.com to 127.0.0.1 so that you could test out different_usernames.example.com and make sure that your server-side code picks it up.

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding. I had tried using dnsmasq but it not work on linux-ubuntu as expected. So if you need to resolve *.example.com to 127.0.0.1 for testing purpose you may need to follow other guide. If you need to effectively block all connection to a domain and its subdomain, you may considering using my guide. Tks

Comment: You can also go to dnsdumpster.com to get list of all subdomain. It's just a matter of copy and paste. Host file need resolve subdomain to a specific IP before transfer to 127.0.0.1. That's why using wildcard is not possible in host file.