# Dynamic sub-domain creation on new User registration in laravel 5 and WampServer

Tags: php, apache, laravel, wamp

I want to assign a Specific subdomain to each user after registration based on her Username on the local wampServer for a domain like `tc.dev`

I've done all steps that been said in [This Topic](https://serverfault.com/questions/275303/virtualhost-wildcard-subdomains) or other similar topics on the web.

This is configuration  that i added to **httpd-vhosts.conf** file:

```
    <VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot "D:/wamp/www/tc/public/"
ServerName tc.dev
ServerAlias *.tc.dev
<directory "D:/wamp/www/tc/public/">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride all
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from all
</directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

And this is what I added to **C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc\hosts** file :

```
127.0.0.1   tc.dev  
127.0.0.1   *.tc.dev
```

and this is My route :

```
Route::group(['domain' => '{account}.tc.dev'], function () {
        Route::get('/', function ($account, $id) {
            return view('main.pages.user.index');
        });
    });
```

`tc.dev` works fine but any subdomain that I test does not work and `index` view not shown.

what is problem and solution?

**Update**:

According to [Wildcards in a Windows hosts file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9695861/498504) , now sub-domain works as main domain But based on route that I wrote `main.pages.user.index` does not show and `index.php` file in `DocumentRoot "D:/wamp/www/tc/public/"` Is shown.

It seams this route does not consider.

Comment: Not too familiar with windows lately as I'm on ubuntu, with nginx but I did find this -- http://stackoverflow.com/a/25391876/1970955 -- you may need to create a PAC file...

Comment: You cannot use wildcards in your host file. But there are other thirdparty softwares out there which creates a custom dns, and allows wild cards. Try them. Or you can manually create a virtual host easily with this batch script i wrote a few months ago. If you would like to try it, here is the link https://github.com/mln-mln-mln/Wamp-Virtual-Host-Creator

Comment: @MilanMaharjan,I try your batch script , main domain (`tc.dev`) works fine but a sub domain like `test.tc.dev` does not work and give me `Forbidden` error. Should I also do extra work in addition to your script ?

Comment: did you setup the host and httpd-vhost file path correctly by editing the script? can you check if the virtual host entry was correctly added to the vhosts file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally after Many research and try different ways I could solve problem.

after using [Acrylic DNS Proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9695861/498504) , I must use two different root for main and sub domains .

This for Main Domain :

```
// Match my own domain
Route::group(['domain' => 'tc.dev'], function()
    {
    Route::any('/', function()
    {
        return 'My own domain';
    }); 
});
```

And another for handling subdomains :

```
Route::group(['domain' => '{subdomain}.tc.dev'], function()
{
    Route::any('/', function($subdomain)
    {
        return 'Subdomain ' . $subdomain;
    });
});
```

In fact The main thing was that I must to use another Route to control routes that acts On main Domain While I was ignored.