# Apache2 virtualhost ServerAlias not working

Tags: php, apache2, subdomain, alias

I am using Laravel 5.4 .(Apache 2.4.8)

/etc/hosts:

```
127.0.0.1 project.local
```

/etc/apache2/sites-available/project.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/project/public
ServerName project.local
ServerAlias *.project.local
<Directory /var/www/html/project/public>
   Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
   AllowOverride all
   Order Deny,Allow
   Deny from all
   Allow from all
</Directory>
```

commands:

```
sudo nano /etc/hosts
sudo nano /etc/apache2/sites-available/project.conf
sudo a2ensite project.conf
sudo service apache2 reload
```

project.local ~> Works

somesubdomain.project.local or www.project.local ~> Not working .

Any help ? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You still need to add an entry in your hosts file for every subdomain you want to hit:

**/etc/hosts**

```
127.0.0.1 project.local www.project.local somesubdomain.project.local
```

Please note that the hosts file does not support wildcard domains.  For example:

```
127.0.0.1 *.project.local # WILL NOT WORK
```

There is another answer on stackoverflow [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20446930/how-to-put-wildcard-entry-into-etc-hosts) that suggests using [DNSMASQ](http://www.thekelleys.org.uk/dnsmasq/doc.html) to achieve what you are trying to do.  Otherwise you may want to consider setting up a DNS server.  (See [BIND](https://www.isc.org/downloads/bind/) or [PowerDNS](https://www.powerdns.com/downloads.html)).  Depending on how much network access you have, your router may be able to help out too.

Comment: Thanks for comment . But still not working .

This site can’t be reached

ERR_ICANN_NAME_COLLISION

Comment: Can you be more explicit about what isn't working? Is Apache sending you to the content of the wrong domain? Is the host simply not found?

Comment: Sorry bad english . I want to create subdomain in Laravel dynamically?

Comment: 127.0.0.1 somesubdomain.project.local ~> Works . But i want to create subdomain dynamically .
127.0.0.1 *.project.local i tried it xD . Not working

Comment: @TodOdKhurelbaatar updated answer.  Probably not the answer you wanted, but should at least set you in a working direction.