# How to properly setup multitenant (subDomains) in a LEMP/Laravel 5.8 for local (DEV) environment?

Tags: laravel, nginx, subdomain, dnsmasq

I am running ubuntu 16.04 with PHP 7.1, NGINX and Laravel 5.8.

My goal is to create a multitenant app in my local (dev) environment.

The root url is `myapp.com`. I want to retrieve from the URL: `account1.myapp.com`, `account2.myapp.com`, `...` and display back the string `account1`, or `account2`, `...` .

After passing trough some posts:

1. [Use /etc/hosts to direct wildcard domain name](https://askubuntu.com/questions/743050/use-etc-hosts-to-direct-wildcard-domain-name)
2. [How to put wildcard entry into /etc/hosts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20446930/how-to-put-wildcard-entry-into-etc-hosts)
3. [Multi-Tenant Laravel on Ubuntu](https://medium.com/@dlimars/configura%C3%A7%C3%A3o-de-subdom%C3%ADnios-local-apache-dnsmasq-laravel-6fcdcbea5bb6?fbclid=IwAR1gJEoH_7LySNj4lVpeyVXX_9wnbzUKksVwp5XgXB_SMZTQHVznsbcUGa8)
4. [Wildcard in /etc/hosts file](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3352/wildcard-in-etc-hosts-file)

I've learned that I should:

1. Install and setup dnsmasq `/etc/dnsmasq.conf (address=/myapp.com/127.0.0.1)`
2. [Set the routes in Laravel to retrieve the subdomains](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/routing#route-group-sub-domain-routing)
3. Set the hosts (127.0.0.1 myapp.com)
4. Set the `/etc/nginx/sites-available/myapp.com.conf (server_name *.myapp.com myapp.com;)`

After all that steps,
the url myapp.com is working good `Route::get('/', 'HomeController@index');`, but the url http://account1.myapp.com/, still not working (This site can’t be reached)

I can't figure out what I am doing wrong.
Some help?

That is the code I have so far:

### ROUTE

```
Route::domain('{account}.myapp.com/')->group(function ($account) {
    return $account;
});

Auth::routes();

Route::get('/', 'HomeController@index');
```

### /etc/hosts

```
127.0.0.1       myapp.com
```

### /etc/nginx/sites-available/myapp.com.conf

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name *.myapp.com myapp.com;
    root /var/www/vhosts/myapp.com/public;

    index index.html index.htm index.php;

    charset utf-8;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

    access_log off;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/myapp.com-error.log error;

    error_page 404 /index.php;

    sendfile off;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.1-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
        fastcgi_buffer_size 16k;
        fastcgi_buffers 4 16k;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }

    client_max_body_size 1000m;
}
```

### /etc/dnsmasq.conf

```
# Configuration file for dnsmasq.
#

address=/myapp.com/127.0.0.1

# Format is one option per line, legal options are the same ...
...
```